# Are temporary accommodations where non-resident foreigners carry out their Obligatory Preventive Isolation designated by the Ecuador authorities?

Tags: international-travel, accommodation, covid-19, ecuador, quarantine

I read on https://www.aviacioncivil.gob.ec/que-debemos-saber-antes-durante-y-despues-de-un-viaje-en-tiempos-de-covid-19/ ([mirror](https://archive.vn/1RGHZ)) (translated to English by Google):

> Travelers will be asked for a negative result of a PCR test, performed up to 7 days before the trip. In the event that the PCR test cannot be performed in the country of origin, the passenger, upon arrival in Ecuador, will undergo the test to detect SARS-CoV-2.
>
> Non-resident foreigners will carry out their APO (Obligatory Preventive Isolation) in temporary accommodation.

Are temporary accommodations where non-resident foreigners carry out their APO (Obligatory Preventive Isolation) designated by the Ecuadorian authorities, or can the non-resident foreigners choose them themselves (e.g., renting Airbnb)?

Answer (score 2):

According to the web site of the [US Embassy in Ecuador](https://ec.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information-ecu-2/):

> ...
>
> The Government of Ecuador requires all travelers who do not provide
> the results of a PCR test to undertake, at their own expense, a PCR
> test upon arrival.  The traveler must then proceed immediately to
> quarantine in a **hotel, hostel, motel or other temporary
> accommodation authorized for such purpose**
>
> ...

<sup>(my emphasis)</sup>

There's nothing to indicate whether you can choose which authorised accommodation you use. Probably, you'll be sent somewhere where there's room.

Comment: According to the link the OP provided it has to be in the same city as the one you arrived in Ecuador at.